# Firefox on resize delay with javascript/jquery

Tags: jquery, firefox, css-float, window-resize

Lately I have a hard time with firefox (up to date 56.0.2) which doesn't seem to be tolerant with sub-pixels rendering (it seems to manage fractional pixels its own way).

For instance, if I have, let's say, 7 tabs floating in a containing div and I apply a width to each of these tabs equal to  "containerDiv/7" pixels, this will work seamlessly on Chrome, Safari, Opera (the ones I tested) where those tabs will be lined up horizontally while, in Firefox, the last tab will flicker and go up and down when resizing the window. When the resizing is over, it might end up lined up or not, depending on the way it rounded the value of the pixels.

I made some research and it looks like all browsers don't handle the decimals the same way when it comes to managing pixels on screen.

Of course, this could be handled with CSS and percentages but this becomes difficult when some of your elements have borders and others don't.

So, I tested a small jquery script to workaround this:

```
function testWidth(){
    var containingDivWidth= $('#containingDiv').width();
    var numBorders = 6;
    var numItems   = 7;
    var totalWidth = containingDivWidth - numBorders;       
    var itemWidth  = (Math.round(totalWidth/numItems))      
    var remainder  = totalWidth - (itemWidth*numItems);

    $('.tab').css('width',itemWidth+'px');
    $('.tab:nth-child(7)').css('width',itemWidth+remainder+'px');
};

$(document).ready(function()      {testWidth();});  
window.onresize = function(event) {testWidth();};
```

Of course, this is not optimal but it is easy to read.

Here is the html, just in case

```
<div id="containingDiv">
    <div class="tab"></div>
    <div class="tab"></div>
    <div class="tab"></div>
    <div class="tab"></div>
    <div class="tab"></div>
    <div class="tab"></div>
    <div class="tab"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
<style>
    #containingDiv{
        width:100%;
        height:40px;
        background:red;
    }
    .tab{
        float:left;
        height:40px;
        border-right:1px solid black;
        background:green;
    }
    .tab:nth-child(7){
        border-right:none;
    }
</style>
```

So, yes, now it works on all browsers, Firefox included.
...when the window doesn't resize.

If the window resizes, Firefox continues to act like before as the last tab is flickering up and down when resizing.

But there is one difference though: at the end of the resizing, the tabs will be lined up.
I checked in real time, the total width of all the tabs always equal the width of the container div, at any time, even when resizing.

So, it seems that Firefox takes some fraction of seconds before recalculating the tabs width when resizing.

This assumption is backed up by the fact that the problem only appears when horizontally resizing the window down, not up.
This seems to show that when resizing down,the sum of the tabs is, for a fraction of second, larger than the containing div, until the calculation is done.
Obviously, when resizing up, the containing div will always be larger, so the problem won't occur.
So this looks like a latency/delay problem to me.

Anyway, I'm back to square one.
Sub-pixels rendering is not working and recalculation while resizing seems to imply a delay and these both, only with Firefox (against Chrome, Safari and opera on Mac which do well in both cases).

What can I do?

Note 1: I could use tables for this but this example is just an example as there are mutliple instances when I need this kind of calculation that can't be handled with tables.
That is not the first time I have this issue with Firefox in various situations.
This is just an example to put the problem in a clear context.
So, suggesting a workaround like tables for this example specifically won't help.

Note 2: However, if there is a way to solve the sub-pixels rendering problem, I would much prefer that instead of creating a function to just prevent getting pixels with decimals because this is time consuming for something tha seems trivial to other browsers (even though the "on resize" latency problem bugs me). Moreover, with a function like this, one of the tabs will always be larger or narrower than the others, which is not elegant as a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Resize has the potential to fire a ton of times.  What I would suggest is looking into throttling or debouncing the resize logic so that it does not fire for every event.  Also you should look into not performing dom lookups inside a resize event handler to increase the speed by which it executes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. "What I would suggest is looking into throttling or debouncing the resize logic so that it does not fire for every event". Yes, but that defeats the whole point as I need the divs to be always lined up, even when resizing the window. I don't care about the "resize" event per se. what i would like is to find a way for Firefox to manage that simple thing that is to keep floated divs floating when the sum of their widths is not bigger than their container. No matter how, as long as it works without a table or percentages (they can lead to decimals that FF doesn't like).

Comment: I don't know if I made myself clear. What i meant is that, i don't see how I can update the width of my container in order to resize the tabs accordingly without probing the container div at any time.
Using css only will not take into consideration the fact that some tabs might have borders while others don't, as the css "width" property is not considering the borders.
So, I have to use js to take those borders into acccount. But then, I have to recalculate the width at any given time which seems to be heavy duty to FF. So, I'm stuck for something quite simple in appearance.

Comment: @BachirMessaouri are you not able to use the CSS box-sizing property like so `box-sizing: border-box;`? That way the borders are accounted for in the total width. Another question, have you tried using CSS flexbox to solve this?

Comment: I didn't know about this property. I will look into that and get back to you.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. It seems overly complicated for what i does but it works. I believe it's like everything else: it needs some practice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an all CSS no javascript solution, try setting `display: flex` on your container, and `flex: 1 1 auto` on the children of the container. This should prevent the jitter you are seeing in Firefox from happening.

Setting `flex: 1 1 auto` let's flexbox automatically distribute the width between each of the children in the flex row.

For a very comprehensive look at flexbox, check out [this guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
#containingDiv{
        width:100%;
        height:40px;
        background:red;
        display: flex;
    }
  .tab{
      flex: 1 1 auto;
      height:40px;
      border-right:1px solid black;
      background:green;
  }
  .tab:nth-child(7){
      border-right:none;
  }
```

```html
<div id="containingDiv">
    <div class="tab"></div>
    <div class="tab"></div>
    <div class="tab"></div>
    <div class="tab"></div>
    <div class="tab"></div>
    <div class="tab"></div>
    <div class="tab"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't know about this property. I will look into that and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: @BachirMessaouri no problem, I also added a link to my answer where you can learn more about flexbox.

Comment: Thank you very much Dylan. I managed to do what I needed to do using flex. It's sometimes unclear where it should be put and how far it propagates, in particular when flexed divs are nested, but It's a matter of practice. Thanks again!